# How to create dropdown from model?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have two models:

```
public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int ClosedReasonId { get; set; }
    public CloseReasonType CloseReasonType { get; set; }
}

public class CloseReasonType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to create a view which has a form for adding questions and a dropdown for CloseReasonType.

```
@page
@model RazorPagesQuestion.Pages.Questions.CreateModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>Question</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Question.Title" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Question.Title" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Question.Title" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Question.CloseReasonType" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="Question.CloseReasonType" class="form-control"
                        asp-items="Model.CloseReasonType">

                </select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Question.CloseReasonType" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Of course when I just added `asp-items="Model.CloseReasonType"` to my select tag helper it didn't populate the dropdown with options. How can I populate the options?

I added this to my CreateModel class

```
    [BindProperty]
    public Question Question { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public List<SelectListItem> CloseReasonType { get; }
```

All the examples I have seen show how to create the list out of hardcoded values.

The full class:

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly RazorPagesQuestion.Data.RazorPagesQuestionContext _context;

    public CreateModel(RazorPagesQuestion.Data.RazorPagesQuestionContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        return Page();
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public Question Question { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    public List<SelectListItem> CloseReasonType { get; }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        _context.Question.Add(Question);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToPage("./Index");
    }
}
```

Comment: you would need to populate the collection on page load. Show the relevant get and post members of the page model

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to populate the select list for it to display on the page

Assuming your DbContext has a `CloseReasonTypes` property

```
//...

private void loadCloseReasonTypes() {
    CloseReasonTypes = new SelectList(_context.CloseReasonTypes, nameof(CloseReasonType.Id), nameof(CloseReasonType.Name));
}

public IActionResult OnGet() {
    loadCloseReasonTypes();
    return Page();
}

public SelectList CloseReasonTypes { get; set; }

[BindProperty]
public Question Question { get; set; }

//...
```

Update the view to bind to the relevant property on the model.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="Question.CloseReasonId" class="control-label">Close Reason</label>
    <select asp-for="Question.CloseReasonId" class="form-control"
            asp-items="Model.CloseReasonTypes">

    </select>
    <span asp-validation-for="Question.CloseReasonId" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

The list will also need to be repopulated if the post was not successful as the page will reload, clearing the select list.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync() {
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
        loadCloseReasonTypes();
        return Page();
    }

    _context.Question.Add(Question);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return RedirectToPage("./Index");
}
```